# The set of all $x$ such that $xHx^{-1}\subseteq H$ is a subgroup, when $H\leq G$

Tags: group-theory

I found this problem in a textbook of abstract algebra:

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Prove that $$\{x\in G:xHx^{-1}\subseteq H\}$$ is a subgroup of $G$.

It's easy to prove that the set is closed under multiplication, but I'm stuck on proving that it is closed under inverses.

If $H$ is finite, say $H=\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$, suppose $x$ is an element of the set. Then $xa_1x^{-1},\ldots,xa_nx^{-1}$ are all distinct, hence they are exactly $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, in some order. Therefore any element $b\in H$ can be written as $xcx^{-1}$ for some $c\in H$, and hence $x^{-1}bx=x^{-1}(xcx^{-1})x=c$ is also in $H$. So $x^{-1}$ is also an element of the set.

However, the above method does not work if $H$ is infinite. The main idea is to prove that $x^{-1}ax\in H$ for every $a\in H$, given that $xax^{-1}\in H$ for every $a\in H$. I was trying to do some substitutions of $a$ to get the required result, but I can't seem to get the $x^{-1}$ to the left.

Any help would be appreciated. It may be worth mentioning that I just started learning this group theory thing for a few days, so please adjust your explanation accordingly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 38):

The reason you are having trouble proving it is that it is not true as stated.

For a heavy-handed example, let $G$ be the free group on $x$ and $y$, and let $H$ be the subgroup generated by all elements of the form $x^nyx^{-n}$ with $n\gt 0$.

Then for any $a\in H$ we have $xax^{-1}\in H$. However, $x^{-1}yx\notin H$, because any element of $H$ is a word that starts with a nonnegative power of $x$.

To fix the problem, you would need to require $xHx^{-1}=H$, rather than $xHx^{-1}\subseteq H$. Then your argument would go through in the infinite case as well.

---

Okay, here's an example you can get your hands on (courtesy my Math 257 notes with T.Y. Lam, Spring 97):

Let $G$ be the group of all invertible $2\times 2$ matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$, $G=\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$.

Let $H$ be the subgroup given by
$$ H = \left\{\left.\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & m\\
0 & 1\end{array}\right)\in G\ \right|\ m\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}.$$
Let 
$$x = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 0\\
0 & 1\end{array}\right), \qquad x^{-1} = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
\textstyle\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right).$$
Then for every $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ we have:
$$\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & m\\0 & 1\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{cc}\textstyle\frac{1}{2}&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)
&= \left(\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 2m\\0 & 1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\textstyle\frac{1}{2}&0\\0 & 1\end{array}\right)\\
&= \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2m\\
0 & 1\end{array}\right)\in H.
\end{align*}$$
So $xHx^{-1}\subseteq H$. However, even though
$$ \left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\0&1\end{array}\right)\in H,$$
we have
$$\begin{align*}
x^{-1}\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\0&1\end{array}\right)x &= \left(\begin{array}{cc}
\textstyle\frac{1}{2} & 0\\0 &1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}2 & 0\\0&1\end{array}\right)\\
&= \left(\begin{array}{cc}
\textstyle\frac{1}{2}&\textstyle\frac{1}{2}\\0&1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}2&0\\0&1
\end{array}\right)\\
&= \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \textstyle\frac{1}{2}\\0&1\end{array}\right)\notin H.
\end{align*}$$
So $x\in \{g\in G\mid ghg^{-1}\in H\text{ for all }h\in H\}$, but $x^{-1}\notin\{g\in G\mid ghg^{-1}\in H\text{ for all }h\in H\}$. So the set need not be closed under inverses.

Comment: It's a relief to know that the question is wrong, because the other questions in the set are merely computations and short proof exercises. I suspected that something was weird here, but didn't go as far to find a counterexample because I thought that the textbook couldn't be wrong.

Comment: @fred: Which textbook is it?

Comment: "A Book of Abstract Algebra" by Charles Pinter.

Comment: @fred Looking at my copy of Pinter you appear to have mis-copied the problem. The original statement is show that $K=\{x \in G : xax^{-1} \in H \text{ iff } a \in H\}$ if a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @Jacob: That would indeed make the problem true, since that would correspond to $xHx^{-1}=H$, instead of $xHx^{-1}\subseteq H$.

Comment: In my copy, it's written "for every" instead of "iff". Probably the author correct it in the newer edition.

Comment: @fred: I just posted an example you should be able to verify.