# How can I prove that this group is isomorphic to a semidirect product?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=\langle x,y,z:xy=yx,zx=x^2z,zy=yz\rangle $, I think that this group is a semidirect product, my first attempt was to prove that this was isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2\rtimes_\varphi\mathbb{Z}$, where $\varphi(1)((1,0))=(2,0)$ and $\varphi(1)((0,1))=(0,1)$. If $x=((1,0),0),y=((0,1),0),z=((0,0),1)$, then $x,y,z$ satisfies those relations. But I noticed that $\varphi(1)\not\in\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}^2)$. How can I fix this? (actually I'm not sure that $G$ is a semidirect product, so if you can prove that it is not, that's fine).

EDIT: the subgroup $\langle  x,y\rangle $ is normal in G, and $\langle x,y\rangle \cap\langle z\rangle=1$ because if we add the relations $x=y=1$ we obtain the cyclic group generated by $z$. So $G=\langle x,y\rangle\rtimes_\varphi\langle z\rangle $ with $\varphi(z)(x)=zxz^{-1}=x^2$ and $\varphi(z)(y)=y$, but I want to be more explicit and find out to what semidirect product $G$ is isomorphic

Comment: The group is a *direct* product, $\langle x,z\rangle\times\langle y\rangle$.

Comment: yeah but I want to understand if $G$ is a semidirect product of the type $<x,y>\rtimes_\varphi<z>$, I edited the question

Comment: I don't think $\langle x,y\rangle$ is normal in $G$. You need to show that it is invariant under conjugation by $z$ **and** by $z^{-1}$ ($z$ does not suffice). Is $z^{-1}xz\in\langle x,y\rangle$?

Comment: That is: it is a common mistake to think that if $G=\langle X\rangle$, then in order to show $N\triangleleft G$, it suffices to check that $xNx^{-1}\subseteq N$ for all $x\in X$. You either need to show $xNx^{-1}=N$ for all $x\in X$, or you need to show $xNx^{-1}\subseteq N$ **and** $x^{-1}Nx\subseteq N$ for all $x\in X$.

Comment: See [the discussion here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75613/the-set-of-all-x-such-that-xhx-1-subseteq-h-is-a-subgroup-when-h-leq-g) to see why the set of $x$ such that $xNx^{-1}\subseteq N$ need not be closed under inverses. So the fact that $z$ satisfies $z\langle x,y\rangle z^{-1}\subseteq \langle x,y\rangle$ does not suffice to conclude $\langle x,y\rangle$ is normal.

Comment: Your are right, if $z^{-1}xz=x^iy^j$ then we get $x=x^{2i}y^j$ that is not possible because $<x,y>\cong\mathbb{Z}^2$, am I right?

Comment: Showing that $\langle x,y\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}^2$ is not immediate, but I think that's right. In any case, the subgroup is not normal, so that's why your approach is not working.

Comment: how can I prove that $<x,y>\cong\mathbb{Z}^2$?

Comment: To show that $x$ is of infinite order, show that $G$ has $\langle x,z\mid x^{2^n-1}=z^n=1, zxz^{-1}=x^2\rangle$ as a quotient, and that $x$ has order $2^n-1$ in the latter group. At least, I'm pretty sure that works. That gives you that the order of $x$ is infinite, the order of $y$ is infinite, and of course, $\langle x,y\rangle$ is abelian. P.S. Use `\langle` and `\rangle` instead of `<` and `>`.

Comment: I tried but I'm not able to prove that in that quotient $x$ has order $2^n-1$, could you help me please?

Comment: Killing $y$ gives the group $\langle x,z\ |\ zx=x^2z\rangle$. By the Freiheitssatz, $x$ has infinite order.

Comment: @SteveD: actually we didn't study that theorem, any other idea to prove that $x$ has infinite order?

Comment: @John: What *did* you study? What course is this for? You are asking big questions, and then asking people to walk you through every single step one question at a time. Perhaps if you gave context, people wouldn't be talking past you and wasting everybody's time.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: it's a course of theory of groups, it requires only the basic algebra of theory of groups and what we did is only the definition of presentation of group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's put all the information together...

The fact is that the subgroup $\langle x,y\rangle$ is **not**  normal in $G$, contrary to the assertion in the edit. Although $z\langle x,y\rangle z^{-1}\subseteq \langle x,y\rangle$, we do not have equality, and this implies that the subgroup is not invariant under conjugation by $z^{-1}$.

To see this, we first show that each of $x$, $y$, and $z$ are of infinite order.

It is easy to see that $z$ and $y$ have infinite order: add the relations $x=y=1$ to get an infinite cyclic group generated by $z$. Add the relation $x=z=1$ to get an infinite cyclic group generated by $y$.

Showing $x$ has infinite order seems a bit harder to me to do from first principles. There may very well be something easier, but here is what I came up with:

For each $n\gt 0$, consider the cyclic group $C_{2^n-1}$ of order $2^n-1$, written multiplicatively and generated by an element $a$. The homomorphism given by $a\mapsto a^2$ is an automorphism, since $\gcd(2,2^n-1) = 1$, so $a^2$ is also a generator of the group. Thus, we can form the semidirect product $C_{2^{n}-1} \rtimes C_n$, with $b$ being the generator of the cyclic group of order $n$, where $bab^{-1} = a^2$. Since $a$ and $b$ in this group satisfy $ba = a^2b$, the group $G$ has $C_{2^n-1}\rtimes C_n$ as a quotient, mapping $x\mapsto a$, $z\mapsto b$, $y\mapsto 1$. Thus, $x$ has order at least $2^n-1$ for each $n\gt 0$, and hence $x$ must be of infinite order as well.

Now note that $\langle x\rangle\cap\langle y\rangle = \{1\}$ (again, set $x=z=1$ to see this), it follows that $\langle x,y\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$; the action of $z$ on this group maps $(1,0)\mapsto (2,0)$, and $(0,1)\mapsto (0,1)$. This is a non-surjective endomorphism, so $\langle x,y\rangle$ is not normal in $G$.

The group *is* a direct product, $\langle y\rangle \times \langle x,z\rangle$.