# Example of $aH \subsetneq Ha$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Problem**. Is there an example of a group $G$, a subgroup $H$ and an element $a \in G$ such that $|G : H| < \infty$ and $aH \subsetneq Ha$?

Comment: Do you have *any* ideas about this? For example, "clearly" $\;G\;$ must be infinite and so must $\;H\;$....why? Anything else, say about normality or stuff?

Comment: Of course it is obvious.

Comment: Good you find that obvious. What else have you achieved so far?

Comment: Group must be non-abelian xD.

Comment: Fine. Do you know *any* example of a non-abelian infinite group? If yes, do you know any subgroup in it which isn't normal? And if yes, can you show it has finite index?

Comment: Good group is a group of matrices over, for instance $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Well, we're now approaching something. You have a possible infinite non-abelian group (over $\;\Bbb Z\,,\,\,\Bbb Q\;$ or whatever). What about finite index subgroups there?

Comment: I found out that $\begin{pmatrix}a &b\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}2 &0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2a &b\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ but $\begin{pmatrix}2 &0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}a &b\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2a &2b\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ but unfortunately I can't find appropriate groups and subgroups.

Comment: I want to take $a = \begin{pmatrix}2 &0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $G = \{\begin{pmatrix}a &b\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}: a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ but it is not a group.

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107862/conjugate-subgroup-strictly-contained-in-the-initial-subgroup) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75613/the-set-of-all-x-such-that-xhx-1-subseteq-h-is-a-subgroup-when-h-leq-g/75620#75620).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $aH\subsetneq Ha\Rightarrow H\subsetneq a^{-1}Ha$.

Then, what can you say about $a^{-2}Ha^2$? Generalise.

---

If we relax the "finite index" assumption then there are lots of examples with $aH\subsetneq Ha$. Examples of such groups can be found in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107862/conjugate-subgroup-strictly-contained-in-the-initial-subgroup), and the links therein.

Comment: It also strictly contains $H$.

Comment: Indeed. Now generalise.

Comment: $H\subsetneq a^{-n}Ha^n$?

Comment: ...and apply finite index...(but be careful! this step is non-trivial. There is a possible issue. What is that issue? Why doesn't it matter?)

Comment: Oh, yes, for some $n$ $a^nH = H$ have to be equal to $Ha^n = H$ (since everything is finite). But it means that $H = a^{-n}Ha^n$.

Comment: Exactly! That is a better way of explaining it than I was thinking of - your explanation gets round my "possible issue".