# Can $gHg^{-1} \subseteq H$ but $gHg^{-1} \neq H$

Tags: group-theory

> Does there exists a group $G$ and $H$ subgroup of $G$ such that there
>   exists $g\in G$ with $gHg^{-1} \subseteq H$ but $gHg^{-1} \neq H$

I am unable to find an example and neither I am able to prove otherwise. Please help

Comment: Order of conjugate subgroup is same as order of subgroup so can we conclude from that these are the same groups?

Comment: No, we can't do that if the orders are infinite.

Comment: You can find an example (necessarily infinite) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75613/the-set-of-all-x-such-that-xhx-1-subseteq-h-is-a-subgroup-when-h-leq-g/75620#75620)