# Let $G=\langle a,b\rangle$. Prove neither $\langle a\rangle$ nor $\langle b \rangle$ are normal in $G,$ for $a=(1234)(57), b=(24)(5678)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, normal-subgroups, permutation-cycles

Let  $G=\langle a,b\rangle,$ a group formed by two permutations of $S_8$:

$$a=(1 2 3 4)(5 7)\quad\text{and}\quad b=(2 4)(5 6 7 8).$$

I have to prove that neither $\langle a\rangle$ nor $\langle b \rangle$ are normal subgroups of $G$.

---

I know that if I've got a group called $G$ and its subgroup $H$, $H$ is normal in $G$ if $g^{-1} * h * g$ is in $H$ **for every $h$ from $H$ and every $g$ from $G$**.
 But my doubt is:

$a$ and $b$ are the generators of those subgroups. If I want to see if $\langle a\rangle$ is normal in $G$, is it enough to see if $a^{-1} * a * a$ and $b^{-1} * a * b$ are in $\langle a\rangle$? And the same with $\langle b \rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since general answers have been given, I'm gonna give one with this specific $G$.

If $\langle a \rangle$ would be normal, $bab^{-1} = (1432)(78) \in \langle a\rangle$, but since $bab^{-1}$ moves the cipher $8$ while $a$ doesn't, $bab^{-1} \not\in\langle a\rangle$, hence $\langle a\rangle$ can't be normal.

Analogously for $\langle b\rangle$ noticing that $aba^{-1} = (13)(5876)$ with similar consideration on the cipher $3$.

Comment: Really nice trick!

Answer (score 4):

No, in general you cannot just check $a$ and $b$.  It’s not enough to check all elements in a generating set for $G$.

In general, if $G$ is generated by a set $X$, and $H$ is a subgroup, to check that $H$ is a normal subgroup it is enough to do one of two things:

1. Check that for each $x\in X$ we have $xHx^{-1}=H$; or
2. Check that for each $x\in X$, we have *both* $xHx^{-1}\subseteq H$ **and** $x^{-1}Hx\subseteq H$.

It is not enough to check that for every $x\in X$ you have $xHx^{-1}\subseteq H$, which is what you are proposing. For example, you can see [this previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75613/the-set-of-all-x-such-that-xhx-1-subseteq-h-is-a-subgroup-when-h-leq-g) to show that in general, the set of elements such that $xHx^{-1}\subseteq H$ need not be closed under inverses, so you could end up with the semigroup generated by $X$ rather than all of $G$ if you only check $xHx^{-1}\subseteq H$.

That said, in the **finite** case it will be enough to check $xHx^{-1}\subseteq H$ for every $x\in X$, because the fact that $H$ is finite guarantees you get equality, so you are in fact verifying item 1 above.

Likewise, say you have a generating set $Y$ for $H$. In that case, it is enough to check $gyg^{-1}\in \langle Y\rangle$ for all $y\in Y$ and all $g\in G$. That suffices, because you get an arbitrary power of $y$ because $(gyg^{-1})^k = gy^kg^{-1}$ for all integers $k$, so if $gyg^{-1}\in H$, then $gy^kg^{-1}\in H$.

So, if $G=\langle X\rangle$, and $H=\langle Y\rangle$, it is enough to check that:

1. For all $y\in Y$, for all $g\in G$, $gyg^{-1}\in H$; **or**
2. For all $y\in Y$ and all $x\in X$, both $xyx^{-1}\in H$ and $x^{-1}yx\in H$.

Comment: But if my H is <a>, is it enough to replace H with 'a'? Or I have to try with a,a^2,a^3,a^4,...?

Comment: @Maialen: I’ll add to the answer.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Since each element $x$ has inverse $x^{-1}$, can you explain what the difference is between the two options $1.$ and $2.$ that you listed?

Comment: @healynr: In 1 you prove equality: if you know $xHx^{-1}=H$, then multiplying by $x^{-1}$ on the left and $x$ on the right, you get $H = x^{-1}Hx$. In 2, you are only proving $xHx^{-1}\subseteq H$, from which, by itself, you cannot prove $x^{-1}Hx\subseteq H$. Of course, if $x^{-1}$ is *also* in $X$, that’s a separate issue.

Comment: @healynr: Again, in a finite group you can get away with less, but in the infinite case you may not. In the free group on $x$ and $y$, the subgroup generated by all $y^nxy^{-n}$ with $n\gt 0$ is closed under conjugation by $y$, but not under conjugation by $y^{-1}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you