# Equivalent definitions for a Normalizer of a Subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, definition

I've seen some definitions of a Normalizer that do not seem equivalent to me and was wondering if I am missing something.

**First to setup the basic stuff:**

$H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Denote the normalizer of $H$ as $N(H)$.

**So now the different definitions:**

Group 1:

1. $N(H)=\{a \in G: aha^{-1} \in H \text{ for }\forall h \in H\}$
2. $N(H)=\{a \in G: aHa^{-1} \subseteq H\}$

Group 2:

1. $N(H)=\{a \in G: aH=Ha\}$
2. $N(H)=\{a \in G: aHa^{-1}=H\}$
3. $N(H)=\cup\{Ha : aH=Ha\}$
4. $N(H)=\cup\{Ha : aHa^{-1}=H\}$

**My conclusions so far:**

1. The solutions in Group 1 are equivalent
2. The solutions in Group 2 are equivalent
3. The solutions in Group 1 are not equivalent to those in Group 2 in general.
4. Group 1 basically says to gather all elements for which the conjugate of H is a subgroup of H,
   while Group 2 says to gather all the elements for which the conjugate of H is equvalent to H.
5. If G is finite, Group 1 will be equivalent to Group 2, because $aHa^{-1}$ is a bijective image of $H$ so if $H$ is finite and $aHa^{-1} \subseteq H$ => $aHa^{-1}=H$.
6. So Group 1 and Group 2 are equivalent if G is finite.

**So my question comes to this:**

Is this correct or not?

Comment: To add some more to this question:
It seems to me that the definitions in Group 1 do not make $N(H)$ a group, so unless G is finite in which case Group 1=Group 2 => $N(H)$ is a group. So Group 1 seems like a bad way to define things. So why use the definitions in Group 1 at all?

Comment: The definitions in Group 1 are simply wrong because, as you said, they do not define a subgroup in general. So it is better not to use them at all (unless you are sure that $H$ is finite).

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75613/the-set-of-all-x-such-that-xhx-1-subseteq-h-is-a-subgroup-when-h-leq-g)

Comment: @DerekHolt So why does Pinter use this definition then(Group 1)? Of course he is stating that G is a finite group, so it works, but I still do not see the merit? Isn't it better to just use one of the definitions in Group 2, like Dummit and Foote/Lang/Artin do, so that it works for an infinite group? In general, is there any reason to shy away from normalizers of infinite groups?

Comment: @Everstudent since Pinter is specifically making a definition for *finite* $G$, you answered your own question about why Pinter used a definition that doesn't work in general. Maybe Pinter learned by experience in teaching finite groups that students are more comfortable with the 1st description of normalizers in a finite group even though it is not a good definition in cases *beyond the scope of the book*. Should a group isomorphism be defined as a bijective group homomorphism or as a bijective group homomorphism whose inverse is a group homomorphism?  For first-time algebra students (contd)

Comment: I think the first definition is fine, but from the viewpoint of category theory the first definition is "defective" because it is the wrong notion in some non-algebraic categories (e.g., topological spaces).

Comment: In the question I linked to, in the comments, there is an exchange about the exact phrasing in Pinter. It appears that in an earlier edition it looked at $\{x\in G\mid xax^{-1}\in H\text{ if }a\in H\}$, but in a later edition this was corrected to $\{x\in G\mid xax^{-1}\in H\text{ iff }a\in H\}$. Make sure your Definition 1 in Group 1 is correct; I would not that “for $\forall h$” would literally read “for for all $h$”, which is ungrammatical.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Which later edition are you referring to? I just checked the 2010 edition(I think it's reprinted or something) and it says:
$\{a \in G: axa^{-1} \in H\ for\ every\ x \in H\}$. It does not say $\{a \in G: axa^{-1} \in H\ iff\ x \in H\}$

Comment: @Everstudent: I don't have any edition of Pinter. The comments in the question I linked to had that exchange. Take it up with them. Aside: use `\text{ for every }` to get regular text in the middle of a math formula; otherwise, it comes out awful.

Answer (score 5):

You left one cute one out: the normalizer of $H$ in $G$ is the largest subgroup of $G$ in which $H$ is normal.

Of course, then we have: $H\triangleleft G\iff N(H)=G$.

Comment: For the $\text{Cute one}$ (+1),,,:))