# Let $G$ be a group & $S=\{s_1,s_2,\dots,s_k\}$ generate $G$. Let $H\le G$. Then if $s_iH s_i^{−1}\subseteq H\forall s_i\in S,H$ is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group and let $S = \{s_1,s_2,\dots,s_k\}$ be a generating set of $G$. Assume $H$ is a subgroup. Then if $s_i H s_i^{−1}\subseteq H \forall s_i\in S,H$ is normal.

I was trying to solve a few questions from a practice sheet but I couldn't really understand how to do it.

I tried contraposition and contradiction and I couldn't really get anywhere. I also tried to show that $s_i^{-1}H s_i$ is a subset of $H$ but honestly got nowhere with that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Given any element $g\in G$, write it as a product of elements of $S$. And then expand $g=s_{i_1}s_{i_2}\ldots s_{i_n}$ in $gHg^{-1}$ and evaluate in to out.

Comment: You cannot show that $s_i^{-1}Hs$ is a subset of $H$, because there are examples in which it is not true.

Comment: @DonThousand The problem with that is that you might need $s_i^{-1}$ as well as $s_i$ to express $g$.

Comment: @DerekHolt True, can't edit my comment though. The procedure is still functionally the same.

Comment: In the example given by user1729 in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107862), the hypothesis holds with $S = \{a, t^{-1}\}$, but the subgroup $H$ is not normal.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @DerekHolt.

Comment: Here's [another example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75613/the-set-of-all-x-such-that-xhx-1-subseteq-h-is-a-subgroup-when-h-leq-g/75620#75620) that also essentially shows that this is not sufficient for normality.