# What are the normal subgroups of $ GL(n,F) $?

Tags: solution-verification, representation-theory

For any $ n $ and any field $ F $ the following is a list of normal subgroups of $ GL(n,F) $:

- The inverse image under $ det: GL(n,F) \to F^\times $ of any subgroup of $ F^\times $
- All subgroups of the group of scalar matrices
- any product of a group of the first type with a group of the second type

If $ PSL(n,F) $ is simple I believe that this list exhausts all normal subgroups of $ GL(n,F) $.

The only cases where $ PSL(n,F) $ is not simple are the two cases $ GL(2,2) \cong S_3 $ and $ GL(2,3) $. (https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/PSLnsimple.pdf)

For $ GL(2,2)\cong S_3 $ there is one extra normal subgroup not of the sort described above, it is the unique subgroup of order $ 3 $, cyclic generated by $ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $, corresponding to the $ A_3 $ subgroup of $ S_3 $.

For $ GL(2,3) $ there is one extra normal subgroup not of the sort described above, it is order $ 8 $ isomorphic to the quaternion group.

Is this answer correct?

Comment: excellent advice! As you will it, so it is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counter-example to your first claim. Let $G\subset GL_4(5)$ be the subgroup consisting of $g\in GL_4(5)$ with $\det(g)=\{\pm1\}$. It is clearly not the first two cases, and the third case must be a subgroup of $\mathbb F_5^\times SL_4(5)=SL_4(5)$.

More generally for any subgroup $A\subset F^\times$ there is a subgroup $\det^{-1}(A)\subset GL_n(F)$, which need not be of the form $SL_n(F)\cdot X$ for some subgroup $X\subset Z(F)$.

Comment: Ok I've updated the list of normal subgroups in the question to include subgroups of the type you describe here, hopefully the list of normal subgroups of $ GL(n,F) $ is complete now!